# PhantomJS cannot resolve react imports; undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, phantomjs, karma-mocha

I have a react/redux app in which we import a localisation function using

```
import { localizedText } from 'utils/LocalizationHelper/textLocale';
```

We then use it in the app anywhere we want to using:

```
localizedText()
```

Our app uses PhantomJS 2.1.1 and Karma. We have this code in one of the components:

```
export const Footer = ({ isIntro, pathname }) => {
    const {marks} = localizedText().mark;
}
```

This works when we run the app. However when we run the test command, PhantomJS complains about:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating '(0, _textLocale.localizedText)().mark')

I am not experienced with Phantom/karma ; what can I do to prevent this error without having to modify the code?